# добавление элемента в массив объектов в объекте

Tags: c#, ооп, классы

Есть класс

```
class Person() {}
```

И есть объект который содержит массив классов Person

```
class Empl(){
private Person[] currentPerson
}
```

У него есть get и set, определен в конструкторе
 
А надо реализовать функцию addPerson, дабы в наш массив объектов добавлять еще одного

Comment: и с какими сложностями вы столкнулись при реализации этой функции?

Comment: Использовать массив в данном случае неразумно. Вы же не знаете заранее какое количество персон у вас будет в `Empl`. Лучше используете `List<Person> _persons = new List<Person>();` а затем создайте метод в классе `AddPerson(Person person);`

Comment: public void addPerson(Person new_per)
    {
    Person[] old_persons = ListPerson;
    old_persons.add(new_per);
    ListPerson(old_persons);
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы не можете использовать `List<Person>`, то вам нужно определиться с размером изначального массива, а затем считать сколько объектов уже добавлено в массив и при его заполнении изменять размер через [Array.Resize](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netframework-4.7.2). Этот метод создает новый массив с указанной размерностью и копирует в него данные из указанного массива, поэтому частое его использование может отрицательно сказаться на производительности.

В итоге у вас получится что-то вроде этого:

```
class Empl
{
    private const int ArraySize = 100;
    private Person[] _persons = new Person[ArraySize];
    private int _addedPersonsCount;

    public void AddPerson(Person p)
    {
        _persons[_addedPersonsCount] = p;
        _addedPersonsCount++;

        if (_addedPersonsCount == _persons.Length)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref _persons, _addedPersonsCount + ArraySize);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Массив - коллекция фиксированной длины, он плохо подходит для реализации подобных задач.

Если вы хотите часто добавлять элемент в конец коллекции - хорошо подойдет List.

```
class Empl
{
    private List<Person> currentPerson;

    public Emp()
    {
       currentPerson = new List<Person>();
    }

    public AddPerson(Person person)
    {
       currentPerson.Add(person);
    }

}
```